# Detecting change between 4 series times polygons (shapefiles) in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, change-detection

I have 4 series times shapefiles (my shapefiles are Polygons), my shapefiles are  about urban(Urban land uses include: Agriculture,Built Up,Bare Land,Water), I want extraction change detection urban in 4 time series(years: 1990-2000-2006-2010).

How can I do change detection between 4 shapefiles in R?

Which book can i find more information about Change Detection spatial in R?

Comment: I don't recommend you R to perform a change detection analysis over polygons. Use QGIS or ArcGIS for that. Other option is convert polygons to raster and perform change detection analysis, but R sometimes fail intersecting polygons

Comment: I would be interested which algorithms would be used, and which R packages would have those implemented in R, @aldo_tapia. I've got colleagues who have a complete R workflow and would like to integrate object-based (polygons) change detection. 

Your answer is from 2017, and R develops quickly. Maybe the problem with intersections are already of the past, or mitigated by another package, like {sf}?

A recommendation on literature on change detection would also be appreciated, to do more research.

Comment: @aae I don't have a solid background in that process. As you say, `sf` is nowadays the best option. Take a look into `tidyverse` and `tidyr`, sp objects are compatible with those packages. I use to compute zonal statistics and do a lot of process with them

Comment: Thanks, I use sf plus the tidyverse. That said, currently, said colleagues re-converted their segmenting to raster data via `fasterize` and are going to do their change detection the "traditional" way.